# matplot and seaborn figure parameters/customizations

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I'm so confused between the two. Every time I make a chart on either pyplot or seaborn, I have to guess what syntax to use. For example, for seaborn doesn't have a title setter so I have to remember to use plt.title. Or, for seaborn charts, plt.xlabel doesn't work, so I have to use sns.axlable(x,y).

And also, randomly I run into the following problem. I'm simply trying to make my seaborn jointplot bigger but I have no success trying both the plt nor the seaborn methods (any tips as to a good documentation showing all the chart parameters??? I find them scattered on the web and it seems like each solution on stack overflow is unique...which adds to the overall confusion).

Here's my code:

```
a = plt.figure(figsize=(30,30))
a.set_size_inches(30,30)
sns.jointplot(x='COAST',y='NORTH',data = data_df, kind = 'kde')
```

Notice I used the plt method and the sns.set_size_inches methods. Both gave me a small chart.

So frustrated with the random overlaps of the two libraries. Any pro tips to lessen the confusion will be greatly appreciated!

edit: This is also true for seaborn's pairplot. I have no success in changing the pairplot's size.

Comment: Which backend are you using?  If you can get ahold of the `Figure` object that seaborn is rendering to `fig.set_size_inches(...)` will adjust the size.  I suspect that `joint_plot` is makeing a new figure (and not using the figure you called `a`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sns.jointplot` creates its own figure instance (as @tcaswell suspected). It doesn't appear that you can tell `jointplot` to use an existing figure. I think you have two options:

1. You can give `sns.jointplot` the `size` option. e.g.:

   ```
   sns.jointplot(x='COAST', y='NORTH', data=data_df, kind='kde', size=30)
   ```
2. You can alter the `JointGrid` figure size after creating it, using:

   ```
   g=sns.jointplot(x='COAST', y='NORTH', data=data_df, kind='kde')
   g.fig.set_size_inches(30,30)
   ```

I presume option 1 is the better option, as it is a built-in seaborn option